# Через какое api проверить наличие товара в магазине ozon?

Tags: python, api

Возникла задача проверить наличие товара в магазине ozon, через seleniumIDE процесс занимает очень много времени, есть ли у ozon полноценное api через которое можно будет узнать наличие товара на складе, необходимо проверять целые категории товаров

Comment: Разумнее спросить это в поддержке Озон.

Comment: Вот документация от озона, как работать с их апи
https://docs.ozon.ru/partners/zagruzka-tovarov/po-api

Answer (score 1):

> есть ли у ozon полноценное api

Да, есть API.

> через которое можно будет узнать наличие товара на складе

Да, через него можно узнать остаток на складе.

Но только для своих (!) товаров
(если Вы поставщик)